# can't get backbone.js to work correctly

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <script src='../client_side_javascript/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script src='../client_side_javascript/bbmain.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
      <header>
          <div class='logo'><h1>logo</h1></div>
      </header>
      <section class='search'>
          <div>
            <form class='main_search_form'>
                <input class='main_search_bar' type='text' placeholder='Type claim here'>
                <div class='main_submit'>
                    <input class='main_submit_button' type='submit' value='Prove'>
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
      </section>
      <section class='arguments'>
      </section>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
(function ($) {
console.log("backbone");
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    events: {
        "click input.main_submit_button":  "addClaim",
    },
    addClaim: function (event) {
        console.log("main submit button pressed");
        event.preventDefault();
        var claim = $('input.main_search_bar').val();
        console.log('claim: ' + claim);
        if ( claim != ""){
            $('section.arguments').append('<div class="claim">- ' + claim + ' <input type="button" class="because_button" value="because"></div>');
        }
    }
});
App = new AppView;
})(jQuery);
```

I've just started playing with this, and can't figure out what I am missing...

The event never seems to get called.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: btw you're missing the point of backbone. You should be using models. I'd start with a `Claim` Model.

Comment: i am just starting out... id like to get this simple view working first.

Comment: my first comment contains a working version of your code.

Comment: can you elaborate on why it wasn't working before? without the template?

Comment: no idea, it worked for me right away. I just added the template to clean it up a bit. Hence the comment as opposed to an answer.

Comment: weird.. when i edit it back to the way it was, it doesn't work for me. Guess I'll have to keep at it.

Comment: nevermind... it did work in js fiddle, just doesnt work in my environment :(

Answer (score 3):

you have a combination of problems with this code.

#### 1: Scope of `events`

the `events: { ... }` configuration uses the `el` that you have specified to bind the events. so, if you have html that looks like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  <button id="bar">click me!</button>
</div>
```

and you have a view set up like this:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#foo",

  events: {
    "click #bar": "buttonClicked"
  }
});
```

this will scope the click event for `#bar` to the el of `#foo`. it's as if you did this with jquery, directly:

```
var el = $("#foo");
var button = $("#bar", el);
button.click(function(e){ ... });
```

Note that when selecting #bar in this example, i'm scoping it to the el variable. Backbone does something similar, to scope the `events` of your view to the `el`.

#### 2: jquery selector executed before your DOM is loaded

you're also likely running into an issue with the DOM not being loaded and available. if your view is defined before the DOM has finished loading, the jQuery call to `el: $("body")` will fail to find anything.

to fix this, you can put the jquery call in the view initializer:

```
initialize: function(){
  this.el = $("body");
  // ... other stuff here
}
```

there are other ways around this, too. since you're already using a module, assign that module to a named variable and then initialize the module in the jquery method, instead of immediately:

```
MyApp = (function ($) {
console.log("backbone");
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    events: {
        "click input.main_submit_button":  "addClaim",
    },
    addClaim: function (event) {
        console.log("main submit button pressed");
        event.preventDefault();
        var claim = $('input.main_search_bar').val();
        console.log('claim: ' + claim);
        if ( claim != ""){
            $('section.arguments').append('- ' + claim + ' ');
        }
    }
});
App = new AppView;
});


$(function(){
  MyApp(jQuery);
})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how what the scoping problem is. The 'el' in my code is 'body', why is it a problem if the click event is scoped there?